# Upgrade Drool 6.0.0 to 6.0.1

Tags: java, drools

I'm looking to upgrade Drools from version 6.0.0 to 6.0.1

The classes RuleBase and PackageBuilder no longer exist.

I can see a lot of examples on the drools site:
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/KIEChapter.html#KIEExamplesSection

What I can't get my head around is which of the may KIA things they now provide replaces the old PackageBuilder and RuleBase classes.

Below is the old code I had, can someone please direct me how I take a drl file and use it in the new 6.0.1 release.

```
final PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
builder.addPackageFromDrl(new InputStreamReader(RuleReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/myRules.drl")));

final RuleBaseConfiguration conf = new RuleBaseConfiguration();

final RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase(conf);
final org.drools.rule.Package pkg = builder.getPackage();
ruleBase.addPackage(pkg);

StatelessSession session = ruleBase.newStatelessSession();
List<Object> context = new ArrayList<Object>();
context.add(rulesParameter);
session.execute(context);
```

Comment: The current version of Drools is 7.12,0 and the current version of the 6.x series is 6.5.0.  Are you sure that you only want to go to 6.0.1?

Comment: I want the smallest step I can to start with, I will move on from 6 to 6.5.0, but I cant work out the PackageBuilder solution.